# How to ignore child elements in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 to extract data from a website about course offerings.

I'm trying to extract just the course descriptions from a `<p>` element.

When I run:

```
course_descriptions = soup.findAll("p")
```

I get:

```
<p><b>INFO 101 Social Networking Technologies (5) I&amp;S/NW</b><br/>Explores today's most 
popular social networks, gaming applications, and messaging applications. Examines 
technologies, social implications, and information structure. Focuses on logic, databases, 
networked delivery, identity, access, privacy, ecommerce, organization, and retrieval.
<br/><a href="https://uwstudent.washington.edu/course/#/courses/INFO101" target="_blank">
View course details in MyPlan: INFO 101</a></p>,
<p><b>INFO 102 Gender and Information Technology (5) I&amp;S, DIV</b><br/>Explores the social 
construction of gender in relation to the history and contemporary development of 
information technologies. Considers the importance of diversity and difference in the 
design and construction of innovative information technology solutions. Challenges 
prevailing viewpoints about who can and does work in the information technology field. 
Offered: A.<br/><a href="https://uwstudent.washington.edu/course/#/courses/INFO102" 
target="_blank">View course details in MyPlan: INFO 102</a></p>,
```

I want to get these results, but without what's in the `<b></b>` tags. How can I exclude them from my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the course_descriptions you can iterate the p tags and then remove the  tag using [decompose](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).

```
text = list()
for item in course_descriptions:
    # some p tags could not have b tags at all.
    try:
        item.b.decompose()
    except:
        pass
    text.append(item.text)
```

The list text will contain the content inside p tags only. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decompose'`

Comment: check for the edit, some p tags might not contain b tags, that's why it was throwing exception.